# Memoized solution to Combination IV on Leetcode gives TLE when an array is used for caching

Tags: python, python-3.x, memoization

While trying to solve [Combination IV](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iv/) on Leetcode, I came up with this memoized solution:

```
def recurse(nums, target, dp):
        
    if dp[target]!=0:
        return dp[target]
    
    if target==0:
        return dp[0]

    for n in nums:
        if n<=target:
            dp[target] += recurse(nums, target-n, dp)
            
    return dp[target]

class Solution:
    def combinationSum4(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        
        dp = [0]*(target+1)
        dp[0] = 1

        return recurse(nums, target, dp)
```

But this gives me a Time Limit Exceeded error.

Another memoized solution, that uses a dictionary to cache values instead of a dp array, runs fine and does not exceed time limit. The solution is as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def combinationSum4(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        memo = {}
        def dfs(nums, t, memo):
            if t in memo:
                return memo[t]
            if t == 0:
                return 1
            if t < 0:
                return 0
            res = 0
            for i in nums:
                res += dfs(nums, t-i, memo)
            memo[t] = res
            return res
        return (dfs(nums, target, memo))
```

**Why does using a dict instead of an array improve runtime?** It is not like we are iterating through the array or dict, we are only using them to store and access values.

**EDIT: The test case on which my code crashed is as follows:**

nums = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250,260,270,280,290,300,310,320,330,340,350,360,370,380,390,400,410,420,430,440,450,460,470,480,490,500,510,520,530,540,550,560,570,580,590,600,610,620,630,640,650,660,670,680,690,700,710,720,730,740,750,760,770,780,790,800,810,820,830,840,850,860,870,880,890,900,910,920,930,940,950,960,970,980,990,111]

target = 999

Comment: At a first glance it looks to me as if there were more differences between these two programs than just replacing a dictionary with an array.

Comment: I don't think so. If you look carefully, it is the same. Although if you find any other differences that could be helping program 2 run faster, please let me know.

Comment: Can you prepare the code in a way that doesn't require to look carefully, but to make it blatantly obvious that they are the same except exchanging a dictionary with an array?

Comment: One difference, for example, is that in the upper code, `dp[target] +=` happens inside the loop and in the lower code `memo[t] =` happens outside the loop.

Comment: One of the test-cases might have a huge target value, which would make the dict-based code much faster.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, yes my code gave the TLE on a huge target value. But how did the dict based code handle it "faster"? Both mine and the dict code are recursing, passing the target-nums[i] values, both are using the same edge cases. What makes one faster than the other?

Comment: It seems that the max target value is only 1000, which means that my guess is probably not correct here. But, say target was `10**12` and input numbers where multiples of `10**6`. The list-based solution would need to allocate space for `10**12` elements; the allocation itself might exceed the time limit.

Comment: Hmm. That maybe for 10**12, my code crashed at target = 999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two versions of the code are *not* the same. In the list version, you keep recursing if your "cached" value is 0. In the dict version, you keep recursing if the current key is not in the cache. This makes a difference when the result is 0. For example, if you try an example with nums=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10] and total=1001, there is no useful caching done in the list version (because every result is 0).

You can improve your list version by initializing every entry to `None` rather than 0, and using None as a sentinel value to determine if the result isn't cached.

It's also easier to drop the idea of a cache, and use a dynamic programming table directly. For example:

```
def ways(total, nums):
    r = [1] + [0] * total
    for i in range(1, total+1):
        r[i] = sum(r[i-n] for n in nums if i-n>=0)
    return r[total]
```

This obviously runs in O(total * len(nums)) time.

It's not necessary here (since total is at most 1000 in the question), but you can in principle keep only the last N rows of the table as you iterate (where N is the max of the nums). That reduces the space used from O(total) to O(max(nums)).